# Question to find area of quadrilaterals inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry

How do I find area of cyclic quadrilateral with sides $10,15,4,5$ .I have tried to solve it with cosine rule, but I want to know something new, please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Let $s=\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}$ be the semi-perimeter ($a,b,c,d$ are the lengths of the sides), then the area of a **cyclic quadrilateral** is given by
$$A=\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}.$$

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this equation?

Comment: @5xum look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicQuadrilateral.html